# Logging Using Log4Net Was Working in Windows Service, Now Fails In System Tray App

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, log4net, system-tray

As the title says, Log4Net is not working. Although the log file gets created (as a CSV), events are not logged to it. I had this working in a windows service but when I moved the code over to a System Tray application, the logging stopped working. I am out of ideas and could use some suggestions...

Here is the main Program of the System Tray App. I configure Log4Net in the Main method:

```
    static class Program
    {
        private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(HostSwitcher.Program));

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

            if (!SingleInstance.Start()) { return; }
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            try
            {
                var applicationContext = new CustomApplicationContext();

                Application.Run(applicationContext);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Program Terminated Unexpectedly",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            SingleInstance.Stop();

        }

    }
```

Here is my app.config file:

```
      <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net"/>
  </configSections>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add
            name="textWriterTraceListener"
            type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
            initializeData="C:\temp\log4net.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
      <appender-ref ref="CsvFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="LockingModel" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <param name="File" value="C:\temp\emotiv_log.txt"/>
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="CsvFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <!--<param name="LockingModel" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />-->

      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="C:\\logs\\emotiv_log.csv"></file>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <layout type="DataMindLoggerService.CsvPatternLayout, DataMindLoggerService">
        <header value="DateTime,ElapsedTime,Level,UserId,Action,Value&#13;&#10;" />
        <conversionPattern value="%date{M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss.fff}%newfield%property{ElapsedTime}%newfield%level%newfield%property{UserId}%newfield%property{Action}%newfield%property{Value}%endrow" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

In my AssemblyInfo file, I have the following:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

And, at the top of each class where I am writing to the log file, I have the following:

```
protected static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SomeNamespace.SomeClass));
```

Additionally, I have tried right clicking on my app.config file and compiling with "Copy if newer", "Copy always", and "Copy if never" and none of the above seem to matter.

Any suggestions. The only obvious thing to me thus far is that this was working in a windows service and stopped working in a System Tray app. However, I am out of ideas - suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Could this be a permissions problem?

Comment: Try to enable internal debugging (cf. log4net FAQ http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html)

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I just added internal logging (see my updated my app.config file here). When I re-run the program, no output gets produced. Let me know if anything looks off to you. Thanks.

Comment: have you verified that the app can read and find it-s config file by adding some setting and verify, that this setting was read?

Comment: OK, thanks Stefan for leading me down the path. I has stupidly copied over the wrong app name in my log4net config and didn't update it to reflect the new app name. Silly error. Sometimes I don't see the forest for the trees. Thanks for your help.